# How can I programmatically set up a UITabBarController without giving it an array of view controllers?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

By default, the UITabBarController expects to be given an array of view controllers to display as tabs. However, there may be situations where you want to programmatically set up the tab bar without providing this array.
I'm wondering how i could do this.

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? How can the tabs be added if you don't update the array of view controllers?

Comment: of course! i just want to avoid using arrays and thats because I dont want to get "index out of range" errors.

Comment: Why (or how) would you get an "index out of range" error creating an array to setup a tab bar controller? Perhaps you should update your question with an example of the problem you are trying fix.

Comment: While you're trying to make your apps' UI completely dynamic and your tabbar is configured by server responses, you may get an index out of range error. 
I was just wondering how to avoid using arrays in this case.

Comment: Then the solution is to fix your server response code to avoid index errors. That's a bug in your code that needs to be fixed. Avoiding arrays is not the correct solution since you have to have an array to setup the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the `UITabBarController` needs to have an array of view controllers, but perhaps your code is split up in such a way that no single function or object knows all the tabs.

In that case, start with an empty array. Then, each part of your code that knows a single tab can use the `viewControllers` member and the `setViewControllers` method to add their tab to the array. The `UITabBarController` is smart enough to recognize if some of the VCs are from the original set and keep any state it has associated with it (like if it was selected).

See documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621177-setviewcontrollers